# Vee-validate 4 fails to invoke custom rule at select field

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I have the following snippet, which is just a Select field.

The issue here is that the required rule doesn't invoked at all.

```
<Field name="allowedBetId" v-slot="{ field }" rules="required">
 <select name="allowedBetId" id="allowedBetId" v-model="allowedBetId" class="otw-block otw-w-full otw-bg-gray-200 otw-border otw-border-gray-200 otw-text-gray-700 otw-py-3 otw-px-4 otw-pr-8 otw-rounded otw-leading-tight otw-focus:outline-none otw-focus:bg-white otw-focus:border-gray-500">
  <option value="" disabled>Select Bet Size</option>
  <option v-bind="field" v-for="allowedBet in allowedBets" :key="allowedBet.id" :value="allowedBet.id" >{{ allowedBet.id }}</option>
 </select>
</Field>
{{allowedBetId}}
<ErrorMessage name="allowedBetId" class="otw-text-red-600 otw-text-sm otw-italic"/>
```

Required Custom rule

```
defineRule("required", (value: any) => {
  if (!value) {
    return "This field is required";
  }
  return true;
});
```

Any ideas :)

no other tries